# Using Map Search Box in Tableau as Action Filter

Tags: tableau-api

I have a dashboard where a map is one of the panes - is it possible for the search box within the map to become an action filter?

For example, if the user typed in Atlanta, Georgia and then the rest of the dashboard would refresh to show the relevant data.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I understood you correctly. The functionality you described is supported by default in Tableau.

I created this map

[image: country map]

Notice I have a filter for state.

Then I create a dashboard and pull the sheet I just created.

On the dashboard, I make the Geo State filter into "wildcard match" and thats it

[image: New York]